# JAX-RS consume Map<String, Object> as part of JSON request

Tags: java, json, rest, hashmap, jax-rs

I want to send a `java.util.Map<String, Object>` as part of a JAX-RS JSON param,
I have the following scenario:

```
@Path("/banner")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class BannerImageService extends BaseServiceFacade<BannerImage, Integer> {
```

...

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public List<T> query(MapRequestBeanVO mapRequestBeanVO) {
    try {
        return getService().search(mapRequestBeanVO.getQuery(), mapRequestBeanVO.getParams());

    } catch (ServiceException e) {
        serviceException(e);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        logException(ex);
    }
    return null;
}
```

...

```
public class MapRequestBeanVO extends BaseSemanticNamedVO<Integer> {

    private String query;
    private Map<String, Object> params;

    public String getQuery() {
        return query;
    }
    public void setQuery(String query) {
        this.query = query;
    }
    public Map<String, Object> getParams() {
        return params;
    }
    public void setParams(Map<String, Object> params) {
        this.params = params;
    }       
}
```

I am currently running Glassfish4 Jersey implementation for JAX-RS
Should I include a third party lib to do the work (Moxy - Jackson)? Or will JAXB handle it? What is the best option?

Answer (score 0):

The Best approach I found is to have all objects Strings and then treat them accordingly on the server side when needed so the class would change to be something like:

```
public class MapRequestBeanVO extends BaseSemanticNamedVO<String> {

    private String query;
    private Map<String, String> params;

    public String getQuery() {
        return query;
    }
    public void setQuery(String query) {
        this.query = query;
    }
    public Map<String, Object> getParams() {
        return params;
    }
    public void setParams(Map<String, Object> params) {
        this.params = params;
    }       
}
```